# Problems with pagination/callbacks in aiogram3?

Tags: python, aiogram

Good afternoon! I am writing a bot on aiogram3 to administer the site. Using a bot you can get/change/delete/add users and news. The backend is written in Django using SQLLite and Rest-framework. Data pagination occurs on the back side using the Paginator class. I already use Router in the bot, since the handlers are located in other directories and files.

**Problem:** When displaying all news/users, it is possible to navigate through pages using Inline-buttons. When all news is received, the callback from the buttons works fine, but when all users are received, the callback does not work. The console displays the log: *INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=769373400 is handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=6151615027* It seems to me that the problem appears due to the fact that the routers have unidirectional communication and, since I have the same buttons for both news and users, the program simply does not get to the next router.

Code for connecting routers in *main.py*:

```
dp.include_routers(bot_commands.bot_commands_router)
dp.include_routers(get_news_handlers.get_news_router)
dp.include_routers(get_users_handlers.get_users_router)
```

For news, the callback and keyboard are similar. Initially, the keyboard output function was one for both callbacks, but after encountering a problem, I decided to split it into two, thinking that this would help. Alas, the problem remains.

[Output of all news with a successful transition to a new page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ7GR.png)

[Output of all users with unsuccessful transition to new pages:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E87PZ.png)

Code with pagination:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def pagination(page_number, model):
    get_model = model
    paginator = Paginator(get_model, 5)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    page_previous = page_obj.has_previous()
    page_next = page_obj.has_next()
    all_pages = paginator.num_pages

    return list(page_obj), page_previous, all_pages, page_next
```

Code for catching callback after clicking a button:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(lambda c: True)
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    if 'to users' in callback.data:
        page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
        await state.update_data(page=page)
        paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                                  model=data['all_users'])

        response_text_users = []
        for user in paginator:
            response_text_users.append(
                f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
                f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
            )

        keyboard = get_users_keyboards(page=page,
                                       has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                                       all_pages=all_pages,
                                       has_next_page=has_next_page,
                                       )

        await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```

Keyboard output code:

```
def get_users_keyboards(page, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page):
    
    next_page = page + 1 if has_next_page else page
    previous_page = page - 1 if has_previous_page else page

    buttons = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='⏪', callback_data=f'to users {1}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='◀', callback_data=f'to users {previous_page}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{page}/{all_pages}', callback_data=f'all users'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='▶', callback_data=f'to users {next_page}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='⏩', callback_data=f'to users {all_pages}')
        ]
    ]
    if not has_previous_page:
        del buttons[0][:2]
    if not has_next_page:
        del buttons[0][-2:]
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons)

    return keyboard
```

I will be glad for any hint. Thanks in advance for your time!)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

In the callback from Inline-buttons, I replaced *lambda c: True* with *F.data.startswith('to users')* for users and *F.data.startswith('to news')* for news

Was:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(lambda c: True)
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    if 'to users' in callback.data:
        page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
        await state.update_data(page=page)
        paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                                  model=data['all_users'])

        response_text_users = []
        for user in paginator:
            response_text_users.append(
                f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
                f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
            )

        keyboard = get_users_keyboards(page=page,
                                       has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                                       all_pages=all_pages,
                                       has_next_page=has_next_page,
                                       )

        await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```

Became:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(F.data.startswith('to users'))
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
    await state.update_data(page=page)
    paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                              model=data['all_users'])

    response_text_users = []
    for user in paginator:
        response_text_users.append(
            f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
            f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
        )

    keyboard = get_keyboards(page=page,
                             has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                             all_pages=all_pages,
                             has_next_page=has_next_page,
                             command='users'
                             )

    await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
    await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```